# what is the maximum value of MAXVALUE in sequence in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sequence

Could you tell me what is the maximum/minimum value of `MAXVALUE` in a sequence & what is the minimum/maximum value of `MINVALUE` in sequence?

Answer (score 21):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm

`MAXVALUE` Specify the `maximum value the sequence can generate`. This integer value can have `28 or fewer digits`. MAXVALUE must be equal to or greater than START WITH and must be greater than MINVALUE.

`MINVALUE` Specify the `minimum value of the sequence`. This integer value can have 28 or fewer digits. MINVALUE must be less than or equal to START WITH and must be less than MAXVALUE.

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE supplier_seq
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Answer (score 8):

Max value is limited to 28-digits only.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to mention any value for MAX Value while creating seq.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name MINVALUE 1 NOMAXVALUE INCREMENT BY 1;
```

This will end up creating seq with

`MIN_VALUE  1
 MAX_VALUE  9999999999999999999999999999`